# BottomNavigationBar - should I use Container and align?

Tags: flutter

I have question - I want to create bottomNavigationBar but in some custom way.
Please take a look on this image:
[image: navImage from Desing]

Im begginer so sorry for a question if its a stupid question/
I try to align every item to the bottom but now I don't have any idea how to do it...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:streeti/static/static_colors.dart';

class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomBottomNavigationBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> createState() =>
      _CustomBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 108,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
          topRight: Radius.circular(15),
        ),
        border: Border.all(
          color: AppColors.blueColor,
        ),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        selectedFontSize: 10,
        unselectedLabelStyle:
            const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        fixedColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
              child: SvgPicture.asset('lib/assets/images/email2.svg'),
            ),
            label: 'Nachricht',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
              child: SvgPicture.asset('lib/assets/images/map.svg'),
            ),
            label: 'Karte',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
              child: SvgPicture.asset('lib/assets/images/hot.svg'),
            ),
            label: 'Angebote',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
              child: SvgPicture.asset('lib/assets/images/community.svg'),
            ),
            label: 'Community',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              child: SvgPicture.asset('lib/assets/images/profil.svg'),
            ),
            label: 'Profil',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To adjust the Container so that the middle icon shows slightly above the Container as I understand it, should I use Stack()?

My navigations looks like this right now:
[image: My nav - right now]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the predefined widgets are limited, like the `BottomNavigationBar`, but you are using Flutter, so you can customize and create your own Widgets :D .

I created an example for you, I'm using `IndexedStack` to control the view pages, and a simple `Container` and `Stack` to create the navigation bottom bar (you can extract this in your own widget).

Results:

[image]

Code:

```dart
class MyNewPage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyNewPage({super.key});

 @override
 State<MyNewPage> createState() => _MyNewPageState();
}

class _MyNewPageState extends State<MyNewPage> {
 int _currentPage = 0;
 final int _maxPages = 5;

 Widget _buildPage(String text) {
   return Center(
     child: Text(
       text,
       style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 60),
     ),
   );
 }

 Widget _buildTab(
   String text,
   int index, {
   bool isCenter = false,
 }) {
   return InkWell(
     onTap: () {
       setState(() {
         _currentPage = index;
       });
     },
     child: Column(
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: [
         isCenter
             ? const Icon(
                 Icons.apartment,
                 size: 50,
               )
             : const Icon(Icons.home),
         Text(text),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: IndexedStack(
       index: _currentPage,
       children: List.generate(
         _maxPages,
         (index) => _buildPage('Page: $index'),
       ),
     ),
     bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
       child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
         child: SizedBox(
           height: 100,
           child: Stack(
             children: [
               Align(
                 alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                 child: Container(
                   height: 80,
                   decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                     border:
                         Border.fromBorderSide(BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
               Positioned.fill(
                 child: Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                   child: Row(
                     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                     children: List.generate(
                       _maxPages,
                       (index) => _buildTab(
                         'Home',
                         index,
                         isCenter: index == 2,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the info. But for me I want only to add every label on one line (as in image from design). So later (redirections) I will do mysefl. Can you edit my code to help me - really I don't know how to change this ... ;) ..

Comment: @LukaszAdler it's not possible using `BottomNavigationBarItem` , because it's centering the content, try using custom widgets as my sample

Comment: Ok, thank you - thats works ;)

Comment: And one question - on your example when you click on icon then you have square splash effect. I think it is because svg is square. Do you know how to add circle only splash effect? I try to add Container with BoxDecoration shape: Box.circle but still this splash effect is square (not circle)

Comment: yes, the InkWell widget has a bordersRadius property, you can modify that:  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse/borderRadius.html